# The connection string is invalid mongo db

Tags: mongodb, clojure, monger

I am using monger to connect with the database, but I'm getting that the connection string is invalid:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The connection string is invalid. Connection strings must start with 'mongodb://'
```

Here's my code in which I'm putting the connection string:

```
(let [{:keys [conn db]} (mg/connect-via-uri "mongodb+srv://username:pass@cluster0-ww5gh.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
      fs (mg/get-gridfs conn "test")]
  (defn store-file [{:keys [file filename format content-type]}]
    (gfs/store-file (gfs/make-input-file fs file)
                    (gfs/filename filename)
                    (gfs/metadata {:format format})
                    (gfs/content-type content-type)))

  (defn gfs-find-by-id [id]
    (gfs/find-by-id fs id))
  (defn find-file [id] (gfs/find-by-id fs id))

  (defn find-one [coll query] (mc/find-one-as-map db coll query))

  (defn find-by-id [coll id] (mc/find-map-by-id db coll id))

  (defn find [coll query] (mc/find-maps db coll query))

  (defn insert [coll query] (mc/insert-and-return db coll query))

  (defn update [coll entry query] (mc/update db coll entry query {:upsert true}))
  (defn update-multi [coll entry query] (mc/update db coll entry query {:upsert true :multi true}))
  (defn update-by-id [coll id query] (mc/update-by-id db coll id query {:upsert true}))

  (defn find-page-n [coll query page n]
    (prn "finding" n "items on page " page)
    (q/with-collection
      db
      coll
      (q/find query)
      (q/paginate :page page :per-page n))))
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: The error message gives you a clear hint about the solution! Did you try that?

Answer (score 3):

The connection string, that also allows for the `mongodb+srv` "protocol" was introduced for MongoDB 3.6.  If you instance is of this or higher version, then you must update your `monger` dependency to a current version.  Otherwise use `mongodb` for the protocol (as the error message suggests).